# How to resolve an error I'm getting in a PHP login page?

Tags: php

I am trying to create a login page using wamp server kindly help me with the following code

```
 <?php
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $db ="test"; //database name

        if(isset($_POST['username']))
        {
        $username = $_POST['username']; 
        $password = $_POST['password'];



        $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='$username' AND password ='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($sql);  
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result==1)) 
        {
            echo "logged in successfully"."<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "invalid password or username retry";
        }
    }
 ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>login</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <form name="login"  method="post" action="login.php">
                Username &nbsp;<input type="text" name="username">
                <br/><br/>
                Password &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password">
                <br/><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="login" name="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Would u allow us see your error?

Comment: Can we please make http://xkcd.com/327/ a valid close reason by itself?

Comment: You have not written code for connecting to  DB. It will look something like `$con = mysqli_connect("hostname", "username", "pwd","dbname") or die ("Please check your server connection.") or die("error"); ` Also  mysqli_query() has two parameters

Comment: i got errors in line 10 and line 11

Comment: what is the parameter i missed in mysqli_query() statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you had read some wrong articles and messed up .The correct code should be like this

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db ="test"; //database name

// This line connects to DB
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$db) or die ("Please check your server connection.") ;


if(isset($_POST['username']))
 {
    // use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent SQL Injection
    $username =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']); 
    $password =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

   //write a query to select
   $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username ='".$username."' AND password ='".$password."'"; 

   //execute the written query using mysqli_query()
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   //----------------------^----------- This is the missed parameter
   //check the no of rows returned
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) { echo "logged in successfully"; } 
   else { echo "invalid password or username retry"; }
 }
```

Comment: That's better, since it actually connects to a database, but due to risk of SQL injection one should NEVER put user supplied variables like POST data into an SQL string.

Comment: @JAL Thanks for reminding, pl check my updated answer.

Comment: It's also worth noting that passwords should not be stored in plaintext either - they should be strongly hashed using an appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result==1)) // You are passing boolean parameter here.
```

is incorrect

It should be:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) // You are passing result set here, which is expected.
```